# jquery div slider not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a `div` slider with next and back buttons.  When you reach the end of the `div`s, the next button goes away and vice versa with back button.  My issue is when I press the next button, the slider functions properly but when I press the back button immediately afterwards, it slides back a `div` but then does not decrease the current `div` counter.  It instead increments it by one.  Now if I click back again, it decreases the current `div` by and functions properly.

**jQuery**

```
var div_name = "1";
var current_div = 1;
var first_run = true;

$(function(){

    function scrollToNextAnchor(aid){
        // if this is the first time you've pressed the next button
        if (first_run == true) {
            $(".back").css('display','block');  //display the back button
            current_div = 2; //set the current div to 2
            first_run = false; //set first run to false
        }
        else {
            $(".back").css('display', 'block'); //display the back button
        }
        console.log("Current Div: " + current_div); //output to log

        var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");  
        $('body').animate({
            scrollLeft: aTag.offset().left
        }, "slow",  //perform slide animation
        function() { 
            //this is where I need to put the .attr stuff
            var next_div = "#id" + (current_div + 1); //set next button to next div
            var prev_div = "#id" + (current_div - 1); //set back button to previous div

            if (current_div == 5) { //if you're on the last div
                $(".forward").css('display', 'none'); //remove the next button
                $(".back").attr('href', "#id4"); //make the back button the previous            current_div = 4; // set the current div to 4
            }
            else { 
                $(".forward").attr('href', next_div); //set next button to next div
                $(".back").attr('href', prev_div); //set back button to previous div
                current_div++;  //increment div by 1
            }
        });
    };

    function scrollToPrevAnchor(aid){
        $(".forward").css('display', 'block');  // display the next button
        console.log("Current Div: " + current_div); //output to console
        var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
        $('body').animate({
            scrollLeft: aTag.offset().left
        }, "slow", //perform animation
        function() { 
            //this is where I need to put the .attr stuff
            var next_div = "#id" + (current_div + 1); //set next button to next div
            var prev_div = "#id" + (current_div - 1); //set back button to previous div
            if(current_div == 1) { //if you're on the first div
                $(".back").css('display', 'none'); //remove the back button
            }
            else {  
                $(".forward").attr('href', next_div); //set next button to next div
                $(".back").attr('href', prev_div); //set back button to previous div
                current_div--; //decrease current div by 1
            }
        });
    };

    $(".forward").click(function() { //click the next button
        var div_name = $(this).attr("href");
        scrollToNextAnchor(div_name);
    });

    $(".back").click(function() { //click the back button
        var div_name = $(this).attr("href");
        scrollToPrevAnchor(div_name);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="next">
    <span style="font-size:48px;">
        <a class="forward" href="#id2">&nbsp;></a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="prev">
    <span style="font-size:48px;">
        <a class="back" style="display:none;">&nbsp;<</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You have an additional `<` in your HTMLs markup

Comment: Those are supposed to be the next and back characters ">" and "<"

Comment: OK, you can use `&lt;` and `&gt;` for literal characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My issue is when I press the next button, the slider functions properly but when I press the back button immediately afterwards, it slides back a div but then does not decrease the current div counter.

This is because you're de/incrementing your `current_div` counter on animation complete, rather than immediately. The [`.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) method takes the following arguments:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

Perhaps you should also look at calling [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) on your animated element prior to calling another animation.

Here are two quick fiddles demonstrating the differences between [incrementing on animation complete](http://jsfiddle.net/z5x6a/2/) and [cancelling the previous animation and incrementing immediately](http://jsfiddle.net/z5x6a/1/), I hope they offer some insight.

Comment: I pulled the de/incrementing functions out of the animation and placed them by themselves above the animation and I am getting the exact same result.

Comment: Have you also cancelled the previous animations?

Comment: Yes.  I added a ('body').stop(); to the end of the animations.

Comment: No, you want to do `$("body").stop(true).animate(...)`